# Tkinter: How to use .after and have the time reset with each call

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically I am trying to make a basic Tkinter clicking game, where if you take too long to click the square (2 seconds to be exact), the game will end but if you click it within the 2 seconds given, the square changes spaces. However, I have all but the "after 2 seconds" thing figured out, as I can't see a way to get .after to do what I want. Here is my current code (the non working .after part will be included also). The code isn't perfect but it works. Any advice on what to do next as will be appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import time

# variables defined

click = 0
amount = 1

# define root window
root = Tk()
root.title("Clicker Game")

# set canvas properties
width = 400
height = 400

# set properties of rectangle

xtleft = 180
ytleft = 180
xbright = 220
ybright = 220



# invoke canvas
c = Canvas(root, width=width, cursor="plus", height=height, bg='white')
c.pack()

# when square is clicked
def clicked(*args):
    c.delete('all')
    xpos = randint(1,380)
    ypos = randint(1,380)
    c.create_polygon(xpos, ypos, xpos+40, ypos, xpos+40, ypos+40, xpos, ypos+40, fill="red", outline = 'blue', tags='clicky')
    global click
    global amount
    click += amount
    lbl.configure(text= 'Score:  ' + str(click))
    root.after(2000, end_game)
    

# function for starting game
def start_game():
    c.delete('all')
    clicky = c.create_rectangle(xtleft, ytleft, xbright, ybright, fill="red", outline = 'blue', tags='clicky'),#'changer')
    # playtext = c.create_text(150, 50, text="Play", font=("Papyrus", 26), fill='blue', tags='changer')
    c.tag_bind("clicky","<Button-1>",clicked) 
    c.pack()

def end_game():
    c.delete('all')
    


# create frame to put control buttons onto
frame = Frame(root, bg='white', width=400, height=40)
frame.pack(fill='x')

# put button for quitting game
button1 = Button(frame, foreground='red', text='Quit', command=quit)
button1.pack(side='left', padx=10)

# label for click counter
lbl = Label(frame, text="Start Clicking!")
lbl.pack(side='right', padx=10)

# put button for starting game
button2 = Button(frame, foreground='blue', text='Start', command=start_game) 
button2.pack(side='bottom', padx=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to save the return value from `.after()`, so that you can call `.after_cancel()` on if it the player clicks before the time runs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`after` returns an identifier that can be passed to `after_cancel` in order to cancel the job.

In your case you'll need to define a global variable to save this identifier, and then use it to cancel the existing job before starting a new job.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
after_id = None
def clicked(*args):
    global after_id
    ...
    if after_id:
        root.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = root.after(2000, end_game)
```

Comment: If you initialize as `after_id = ' '` then you can save yourself the check.

Comment: you're a genius, that worked perfectly. didn't realise after_cancel was a thing. thank you very much :)